# memory stream is not expandable on taglib File.save

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mp3, taglib

I used taglib to change some of the mp3 tags it works fine with most files but I get **memory stream is not expandable** error sometimes here's my code:

```
    using var music = TagLib.File.Create(new FileBytesAbstraction(dto.MusicFile.Name, dto.MusicFile.File.GetBytes()));
            var lenght = music.Properties.Duration.TotalSeconds;
            music.Tag.Performers = await db.Artists.Where(a => dto.Artists.Contains(a.Id))
                                                   .Select(a => a.ArtisticName)
                                                   .ToArrayAsync();
            music.Tag.Album = (await db.Albums.Where(a => a.Id == dto.AlbumId).Select(a => a.Title).FirstOrDefaultAsync()) ?? "Single";

            music.Tag.Year = (uint)dto.ReleaseDate.Year;

            music.Tag.Title = dto.Title;

            music.Tag.Genres = await db.Genres.Where(g => dto.Genres.Contains(g.Id))
                                              .Select(g => g.Title)
                                              .ToArrayAsync();

            music.Save(); //error on this line

            var byteMusic = new ByteVector();
            music.RFind(byteMusic);
```

please help I spent 2 weeks on this error

I tried chatgpt, using temp files, sending file stream

P.S:i am using taglib.Audio lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved My problem
I just used a path Instead **FileBytesAbstraction** that I made custom for pass
**Byte[]** to taglib File

```
  string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".mp3";
        try
        {
            using (var tempFileStream = System.IO.File.Create(tempFilePath))
            {
                await dto.MusicFile.File.CopyToAsync(tempFileStream);
            }
            using var music = TagLib.File.Create(tempFilePath);
            var lenght = music.Properties.Duration.TotalSeconds;
            music.Tag.Performers = await db.Artists.Where(a => dto.Artists.Contains(a.Id))
                                                   .Select(a => a.ArtisticName)
                                                   .ToArrayAsync();
            music.Tag.Album = (await db.Albums.Where(a => a.Id == dto.AlbumId).Select(a => a.Title).FirstOrDefaultAsync()) ?? "Single";

            music.Tag.Year = (uint)dto.ReleaseDate.Year;

            music.Tag.Title = dto.Title;

            music.Tag.Genres = await db.Genres.Where(g => dto.Genres.Contains(g.Id))
                                              .Select(g => g.Title)
                                              .ToArrayAsync();

            music.Save();

            var byteMusic = new ByteVector();
            music.RFind(byteMusic);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).